# contar numero de veces que ocurre en una base de datos

Tags: r, rstudio

hola comunidad soy nuevo usando the R y Rstudio 
me gustaria tener su punto de vista para contar el numero de veces que ocurre cierto valor en la base de datos. en este caso manejo precipitacion

```
x     precipitacion
2     35.5
3      0.0
4     49.0
5      2.0
6      2.0
7     33.0
8      9.0
9      1.0
10     1.5
11   175.0
12     0.0
13     3.0
14     0.0
15     0.0
16     0.0
17     0.6
18     1.0
19     0.0
20     1.0
21     0.0
22     0.0
23    15.2
24    16.0
25     0.0
26     0.0
27     0.0
28    13.0
29     5.4
30     6.0
```

utilizo la funcion siguiente para contar cuantas aparaciones tiene el 0

```
contar <- function(x){
  cont<-0
  for (i in precipitacion ) {
    if  (i == 0) { cont=cont + 1 } 
  }
  cont
```

pero me da valores completamente diferentes en el caso del 0 que deberia dar como resultado que aparece 11 veces el cero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El enfoque iterativo que usas, en el caso de R es innecesario ya que el lenguaje esta diseñado para trabajar con vectores. En tu ejemplo, y suponiendo que tuvieras un `data.frame` denominado `df`, contar los valores dónde `precipitacion == 0` es tan sencillo como:

```
sum(df$preciptacion == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

- `df$preciptacion == 0` te retorna un vector de lógicos dónde `TRUE` serán los valores 0.
- Aprovechando que un `TRUE` se coerciona a el valor 1 y `FALSE` al 0, `sum()` nos retornará la cantidad de casos dónde `df$preciptacion == 0`
- Con `na.rm = TRUE` hacemos que `sum` ignore los valores `NA`

Comment: hola Patricio, gracias por tu ayuda, pero no me funciona  `sum()` al momento correrlo me indica [NA].

Comment: Por que tienes valores NA, puedes usar el parámetro  na.rm=TRUE para obviar estos casos, verifica mi última edición